# Word: error 0xc0000142 on app launch

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I've a regular license of Office and today, opening Word, I must first wait for an 'update' of office, than I see a blocking error.

I already tried with both app restore options from advanced option in settings->apps->office->advanced without any results

Also tried from old control panel->installed apps->office->change where I found 2 options to restore

[image: rd]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Error is stille here.

What's the source of the problem? I don't want to reinstall ALL again (it's not the first time it happended)

For reference, I'm on Windows 10 1909

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That looks like a .NET error.

Make sure you have the latest versions of .NET Framework 3.5 & 4.8 installed - [Microsoft Update Catalog [searching ".NET Framework 1909"]](http://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=.net%20framework%201909)

Comment: Thanks. I verified, but all frameworks was already at latest version. Actually, I removed and reinstalled. After reinstallation, all works, but I can no more login using corporate microsoft account... Sad...